# How to execute a webrequest asynchronous to parse json

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, .net-4.8

I need to get a value from an API and I'm using the follow code synchronous.

```
       Dim request As HttpWebRequest
       Dim response As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
       Dim reader As StreamReader

       Try

           request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("http://ecc"), HttpWebRequest)

           response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
           reader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())

           Dim rawresp As String
           rawresp = reader.ReadToEnd()

           Dim jResults As JObject = JObject.Parse(rawresp)
           Label1.Text = jResults("result").ToString()


       Catch ex As Exception
           MsgBox(ex.ToString)
       Finally
           If Not response Is Nothing Then response.Close()

       End Try
```

The problem is that's synchronous, I want to make it async in order not to freeze the form in the while.
How can I async it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily use WebClient and the nuget package NewtonSoft doing something like this:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

Public Class Form1
    Private ReadOnly wc As New WebClient()

 Private Async Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

        'stop timer to avoid simultaneous I/O operations
        Timer1.Stop()

        Dim downloadTasks As New List(Of Task(Of String))

        'download api and add as a task of string
        Dim APIValue = wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync("https://api.etc")
        downloadTasks.Add(Value)
        Await Task.WhenAll(downloadTasks)
        Dim d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))(APIValue.Result)

        Dim Price As String = d("result").ToString
        Label1.Text = Price

        Timer1.Start()
 End Sub
 End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Much simpler with [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient) and [JsonNode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.nodes.jsonnode):

```vb
'// Web API:
'// app.MapGet("/api", () => new { id = 1, result = "100", name = "name1" });

Imports System.Net.Http
Imports System.Text.Json.Nodes

Using http = New HttpClient
  Dim url = "https://localhost:5000/api"
  Dim json = JsonNode.Parse(Await http.GetStreamAsync(url))
  Label1.Text = json("result")
End Using
```

Comment: well, where did you get JsonNode?
is it on which library?
keeps saying Description
'JsonNode' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: @878757 Added required imports. FYI, you can press `Ctrl+.` to show pop-up with suggestions to add these `Imports`.

Comment: I know how to see suggestions, but your import doesn't solve anything also cause it is not even suggested. Mattia solution works like a charm

Comment: @878757 So, what is _wrong_ with my code? I have tested it - and it works. Other case is when you must use dreaded `WebClient`.

Comment: the previous error is still there, didnt change anything importing that.. "JsonNode' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level."

Comment: @878757 And did you add `Imports`? Do you use .NET 5+ or .NET Framework?

Comment: Yeah of course I added the Imports. I'm using 4.8

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240712/discussion-between-johnyl-and-878757).